# Workbench. Как к нему подключиться через редактор?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Прошу прощение за глупый вопрос, но очень хочу разобраться в данной теме! Я пользовался OpenServer для открытия php файлов. Нашёл такой инструмент для визуального проектирования баз данных Workbench и захотел связаться с ним через редактор Sublime Text. Подскажите пожалуйста, как через редактор подключиться к Workbench? Спасибо!

Comment: Workbench - это самостоятельный инструмент... Вам же не придёт в голову "связываться" с редактором Sublime Text из более привычного некоторым товарищам MS Word? вот и тут та же история.

Comment: То есть нельзя путать OpenServer и Workbench?

Comment: Да они вообще никак не связаны. OpenServer - это локальный веб-сервер. Workbench - это штатный GUI для работы с базами данных MySQL-сервера.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я понял!!!

Comment: единственное логичное связывание - подключиться к вашей бд на OpenServer из Workbench'a